# javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: /tab.xhtml @65,50 value="#{stackElement.name}": The class 'java.lang.String' does not have the property 'name'

Tags: jsf, primefaces, propertynotfoundexception

If I add `stackElement` first time it's ok, the output is:

> list size = 1

But after adding second element I get error:

> Error Rendering View[/tab.xhtml]: javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException:
>   /tab.xhtml @65,50 value="#{stackElement.name}": The class
>   'java.lang.String' does not have the property 'name'. ... Caused by:
>   javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: The class 'java.lang.String' does
>   not have the property 'name'.
>
> ERROR [io.undertow.request] (default task-4) UT005023: Exception
>   handling request to /Play/tab.xhtml: java.lang.IllegalStateException:
>   CDATA tags may not nest ...

Why does it happens?

Page

```
<h:form>

    <p:commandButton update="stack" value="Use in expression" action="#{bean.tab}">
        <f:param name="i" value="13" />
    </p:commandButton>

    <p:orderList  id="stack" value="#{expression.list}" var="stackElement" 
            itemLabel="#{stackElement}" itemValue="#{stackElement}" controlsLocation="none" >
        <!-- <p:ajax event="reorder" listener="#{expression.onReorder}" /> -->
        <p:column>
            <h:outputText value="#{stackElement.name}" />
        </p:column>
    </p:orderList>

</h:form>
```

bean

```
@ManagedBean @RequestScoped 
public class Bean implements Serializable {
    @ManagedProperty(value="#{expression}")
    private Expression ex;
    public void tab() { 
        ex.addStackElement( new StackElement((int) System.currentTimeMillis(), "tab") );
    }
    // getters-setters
```

bean

```
@ManagedBean @SessionScoped
public class Expression implements Serializable {
    private List<StackElement> list = new ArrayList<StackElement>();
    public void addStackElement(StackElement stackElement) {
        list.add(stackElement);
        System.out.println("list size = " + list.size()); 
    }
    // getters-setters
```

model

```
public class StackElement {
    private int id;
    private String name;
    public StackElement(int id, String name) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }
    // getters-setters
```

converter

```
@FacesConverter("myConverter")
public class MyConverter implements Converter {

    @Override
    public Object getAsObject(FacesContext fc, UIComponent component, String value) {
        if(value != null && value.trim().length() > 0) {
            try {
                Expression service = (Expression) fc.getExternalContext().getApplicationMap().get("expression");
                return service.getStackElementByName(value);
            } catch(NumberFormatException e) {
                throw new ConverterException(new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, "Conversion Error", "Not a valid element name."));
            }
        }
        else {
            return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String getAsString(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object object) {

        if(object != null) {
            return String.valueOf(((StackElement) object).getName());
        }
        else {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This seems work with simple model like `List<String> list` but what is wrong with `List<StackElement> list`

Comment: You need a converter

Comment: @MathieuCastets What is the idea of using converter? it's usually used for JSF input component.

Comment: Is `stackElement` used as var name anywhere else on the page? Just in case, can you try renaming it (and references to it in `orderList`) to something like `stackElement2`?

Comment: @PredragMaric The `stackElement` used only in `p:orderList`

Comment: If you change column to `<h:outputText value="#{stackElement}" />`, what does it print?

Comment: @PredragMaric   In this case there are no erros but orderList shows elements as `StackElement@1e67e93`

Comment: _"What is the idea of using converter? it's usually used for JSF input component."_. OrderList IS an input componet... You need to use the pojo example like in http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/orderList.xhtml

Comment: @Kukeltje if I use poje example  like in the sample then it works but  the problem is using complex model like `List<StackElement> list`

Comment: The pojo example uses a List<Theme>. So it isidentical. And it uses a converter like @mathieucastets pointed out

Comment: @Kukeltje Where to find the code of `converter="theme"` used in that example?

Comment: https://github.com/primefaces/showcase/tree/master/src/main/java/org/primefaces/showcase/convert

Comment: You can also work with the ready-to-use `ListConverter` from Omnifaces http://showcase.omnifaces.org/converters/ListConverter

Comment: @Tiny the converter is already present but now I can add only one element to list by commandButton

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are few issues with your code.

1. You should use `converter="myConverter"` on your `<p:orderList>` component.
2. Expression bean is of SessionScoped. But you are getting it from ApplicationScope.

Change it to

Expression service = (Expression) fc.getExternalContext().**getSessionMap()**.get("expression");

After making these changes its working.

Comment: I changed the output in view to - `<h:outputText value="#{stackElement.id}" />` and while adding new element it looks like: `1722625713,
1722625713,
1722625713,
1722625713,
1722625713,
1722651963`

Comment: `id` values they must be different

Comment: Those values are based on how you are populating List<StackElement> list in Expression bean. right?

Comment: yes, it starts in `bean` and continues in `expression` but the entry point is `ex.addStackElement( new StackElement((int) System.currentTimeMillis(), "tab")`

Comment: according to consructor the the id values must be different

Comment: What is happening is whenever you are clicking the button it is sending the string "tab" and in MyConverter.getAsObject() method you are calling service.getStackElementByName(value) which is obviously matching the first bean itself all the times.

Comment: Instead of just "tab" try to add some dynamic value "tab"+ i and see.